# Add AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to Biztalk Wcf service

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf, biztalk

I'm trying to get a Biztalk 2009 WCF receive location lockdown per a permissions requirement so only a certain group of users can access the WSDL and service using Authorization Rules in the services web.config

```
<authorization>
<allow users="uuu\InterfaceUser" />
<allow roles="AllowedTeam" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I've enabled the following in the web.config figuring it would do the trick.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and came across the error

*The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.*

I know what I would need to do is add the following:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

to the service, but the generated through the Biztalk WCF service wizard, so I am unsure of how to get this configured.

The receive location is a **WCF-CustomIsolated** , but I am not seeing a behavior in the transport properties to turn on the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute. BindingType is **basicHttp** Security is **TransportWithMessageCredentials**

Any thoughts or guidance would be helpful.

I have to have the authentication on both the service and the wsdl.

Comment: Is it the service itself, just the WSDL or both you want to set auth rules?

Answer (score 0):

After additional research it doesn't look like it will be possible to integrate asp.net compatibility to the service. Which means adding

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

won't be possible.

The solution I did was to infact build a custom behavior to use the ASP.NET URL Authorization Module.

Thanks to Dean May for the solution found at

https://phidiax.com/blog/post/securing-biztalk-wcf-receive-locations